# SQLAlchemy - adding children to a many-to-many relationship using numeric ids

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a relationship as follows:

```
parent_child = db.Table('parent_child',
                           db.Column('parent_id',
                                     db.Integer,
                                     db.ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
                           db.Column('child_id',
                                     db.Integer,
                                     db.ForeignKey('child_instance.id', ondelete='CASCADE')))


class Parent(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    child_instances = db.relationship(
        'ChildInstance', secondary=parent_child, backref=backref('parents', lazy='joined'), lazy=False)

class ChildInstance(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Assuming we have a child instance object, we could just use `append` to add it to the `child_instances` relationship.

However if I want to implement creation of a parent given the child *numeric ids* (let's say because I already have them cached from prior sessions):

```
def create_parent_with_children_ids(children_ids):
    returned = Parent()
    db.session.add(returned)
    #????
```

How can this be done? From simple attempts it seems that `append` on the relationship only works for ChildInstance objects, and I want to avoid querying for them just for this purpose...

Thanks in advance!